# How to update /boot/grub/menu.lst?

Tags: grub, sles

How can I set the ex.: "intel_idle.max_cstate=0" in the boot kernel parameter?

So just want to update /boot/grub/menu.lst, how to do it permanently on SLES 11?

Without using yast.

Or just manually edit the menu.lst file and reboot, and it will be permanent, even after future kernel updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` to add kernel parameters  and then do `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` to update grub.

Edit: I just noticed that you use legacy grub you can manually edit `menu.lst`.

Comment: yepp, manual, thx